# Visual Studio 2017 не выводит символы

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Пишу прогу на С++.
При запуске кода в консоли вместо символов знаки вопроса в квадрате.
Как можно исправить или что подключить?
Дописал пример, спец символы не выводятся с 0 по 49 все знаки вопроса 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 unsigned char GetRenderCellSymbol(unsigned char cellSymbol)
{
    switch (cellSymbol)
    {
    case CellSymbol_empty: 
        return ' ';
    case CellSymbol_wall: 
        return 177;
    case CellSymbol_hero: 
        return 2;
    case CellSymbol_exit: 
        return 178;
    case CellSymbol_orc: 
        return 2;
    case CellSymbol_skeleton: 
        return 2;
    case CellSymbol_stick: 
        return 47;
    case CellSymbol_club: 
        return 33;
    case CellSymbol_spear: 
        return 24;
    case CellSymbol_saber: 
        return 108;
    }
    return '?';
}
```

Comment: А привести здесь код вы не хотели бы?) У вас с кодировкой беда вероятнее всего

Comment: Недостаточно данных - что за символы (вообще все, кириллица, какие-то спецсимволы), откуда они берутся (захардкожены в коде или же читаются откуда-то)? В целом это почти наверняка не та кодировка и решение где-то около вот этой функции https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp , хотя юникод оно вроде бы не съест

Comment: Дописал пример, спец символы не выводятся с 0 по 49 все знаки вопроса

Comment: Канонично все-таки в рогаликах использовать печатаемые символы. Рожицей героя никто не показывает, есть "@".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел)

Правой кнопкой мыши по верху консоли - свойства - поставить галочку "использовать старую версию консоли"